# Adding extra attributes to celery function that can be accessed from custom base class

Tags: python, celery

When defining a celery task function using the `@task` decorator, is it possible to add some extra attributes to the decorator that I can access from my task base class when the task starts without adding new parameters to the task function itself?

Something like

```py
class CustomBase(celery.Task):
     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # do something with foo
         ...

         self.run()

@task(base=CustomBase, bind=True, foo=123)
def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass some variables to the task decorator(with bind=True) it will passes them to the constructor of the Task. and you can access them using self. Just an example of code

```
from celery import Celery, chord, chain, Task

backend = 'redis://redis:6379/'
app = Celery(result_backend=backend, backend=backend)


class CustomBase(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.foo)  # in class
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


@app.task(base=CustomBase, bind=True, foo=123)
def add(self, x, y):
    print(self.foo)  # in task
    return x + y


add.apply_async((1, 2))
```